# How to get google suggestions and put it on UITableView while I typing in UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

This question is probably answered.
I want to make `UITextField` with a suggestion table as shown below like Safari does:

[image: Safari google search]

I know how to get text while typing and search in my `sqlite` or `core data bases` for similar text. But, how can I connect to google or youtube "database" and get suggestions and most importantly show it in `UITableView`.

I tried [this](https://github.com/keyf/AutocompletionTableView) sample, but it only search in dictionary, not for online results!

Please give something to start with! THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google suggestions are put online as an XML sheet, for instance these are suggestions for the word Nico:

http://google.com/complete/search?q=Nico&output=toolbar

After parsing the data you can show it on tableView.

Comment: Maybe you now some good sample, how to implement this xml sheet to table?

Comment: If it worked for you then please accept the answer. Now only you need to parse data and show in your tableView.

Comment: I went on the internet and I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394) It helps to understand, how to parse and show data on UITableView!

Answer (score 10):

Use below to get search suggestions in XML format.

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=SEARCH_TERM

Parse the `XML` and display in your table view.